# Tamil Typesetting using beamer Latex

Tags: beamer, xetex, fontspec, tamil

Here my code for Latex

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latha.ttf}



\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{block}
    \Huge
    fjdkfjd
        தமிழ் மொழி!
    \end {block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output is

fjdkfjd       !

Everthing apart from Tamil
I am using Xetex in Overleaf
How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define serif and san-serif fonts for Tamil, either by using the `polyglossia` package or the `babel` package. [This page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Tamil) lists OTF/TTF fonts that are available on Overleaf.

With `polyglossia`:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{tamil}
\newfontfamily{\tamilfont}[Script=Tamil]{Noto Serif Tamil}
\newfontfamily{\tamilfontsf}[Script=Tamil]{Noto Sans Tamil}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{block}
    \Huge
    fjdkfjd
    \texttamil{தமிழ் மொழி!}
    \end {block}
\end{frame}
```

With `babel`:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import]{tamil}
\babelfont[tamil]{rm}[Language=Default]{Noto Serif Tamil}
\babelfont[tamil]{sf}[Language=Default]{Noto Sans Tamil}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{block}
    \Huge
    fjdkfjd
    \foreignlanguage{tamil}{தமிழ் மொழி!}
    \end {block}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Package babel Error: Neither 0 nor ZERO WIDTH SPACE are available(babel) aware this setting is not safe (see the manual).. ^^I^^I\end{frame}

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: @NewtonNadar An error [babel] seems too drastic. I'll replace it with a warning. I haven't found a reliable source about line breaking in Tamil. Apparently,  it's usual not to divide words and justify with wide spaces. Anyway, try with `HyphenChar=-` in the second optional argument.